# Looking for a macro to increase a number by 1 in a Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2010

I have a Word document that other users can access and change (on the same computer).

At the top of that document is a line that says "Version # XXX".

What I would like is to be able to run a macro that would increase XXX by 1 and save the document.

Is that possible? How?

Comment: What if people open it just to view without making changes? then it will increment unnecessarily...

Comment: The idea is that it would only increment when the macro is run from a shortcut. The macro would not run automatically.

Comment: Yes,  the system removes "hello" as signature and greetings are considered not necessary here. We write questions, not letters:)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Document Property called (say) Revision. You should then be able to display it in a Field and your code can read and write to it via:

```
myDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("Revision").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is ever interested, here is the answer I found.

1/ Insert a field (CTRL+F9) as "{ DOCVARIABLE VNUM }"

2/ Create a macro with the following code:

```
    Sub IncrementVersion()

    On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveDocument
        .Variables.Add ("VNUM")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If IsNumeric(.Variables("VNUM")) = False Then
            .Variables("VNUM") = 1
        Else
            If .Saved = False Then
                .Variables("VNUM") = .Variables("VNUM") + 1
                Else
                    If MsgBox("No changes", vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then
                    Exit Sub
                    Else
                    'nothing
                End If
            End If
        End If
        .Fields.Update
        .Save
        .Close
    End With
    End Sub
```

It works fine for what I was looking for.